# PostgreSQL get data by month

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that will bring all the timestamps in a specific month (in this case, july). However this is hardcoded, I want to write something that will update itself as time goes on (because database I'm using is always updated to current time). For example,

4 months ago from current date as month is april, when I say I want data from 4 months ago I need all data from 1 to 30 april, not the data between 11 august (today) and 11 april

How do I do it?

```
SELECT issued_at 
FROM issuances_extended 
WHERE issued_at >= '2022-07-01'
  and issued_at < '2022-07-31'
  and status = 'completed' 
  and network = 'ethereum'
```

Comment: specific month you need in any case to input by hands (e.g. December 2021). Or you mean the current month?

Comment: Unrelated, but: why did you exclude the last day of the month?

Comment: I can get current month by typing

issued_at >= date_trunc('month', current_date)

this brings data from august 2022 (the month we're in). change month to year and I can get ytd (year to date) data. I want something that will be able to bring data from x months ago. check main post, I will edit it to explain better

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I will update when I fix the main issue, thanks for noticing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want something that will be able to bring data from x months ago.

Then just subtract that number of months from "today":

```
SELECT issued_at 
FROM issuances_extended 
WHERE issued_at >= date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '4 month'
  and issued_at < date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '3 month'
  and status = 'completed' 
  and network = 'ethereum'
```

In August 2022, the above evaluates to

```
    issued_at >= '2022-04-01 
and issued_at  < '2022-05-01'
```

Comment: this seems to work. right now it can show all issuances from april, can I count on this to show from may when 1st september starts? in other words, can it update itself to may at 12am 1st september?

Comment: with this method I can get up to june easily, how do I get july in august 2022? need clarification on how to get previous month's record

Comment: If you want the previous month, then subtract 1 month

Comment: I've figured it out,  interval '1 month' - interval '0 month' gets previous month's data, in this case july 2022